# Write a program that writes every other of the first 100 Fibonacci numbers.(Python)

Tags: python, function, file

I'm pretty new to Python and I'm not even sure where to start. If someone could help, that would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Use `numpy.cumsum(list(range(1,101)))`

Comment: StackOverflow is more of a site to ask specific questions about existing code. It's likely this question will be closed since it's not really in the format of what's allowed on the site. Take a look at the [ask] page.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'll just quickly tell you the answer.

```
# First two numbers of fibonacci sequence
fib = [0, 1]

# Generate the fibonacci sequence
for i in range(98):
    # Sum the last two numbers and append it to fib
    fib.append(fib[-1] + fib[-2])
    
# for i in (0, 2, 4, 6...)
for i in range(0, 100, 2):
    print fib[i]
```

Answer (score 2):

The most basic method (though not the most efficient) would be as follows. First define a function that calculates the Fibonacci number at a certain place. There are 2 approaches to this iterative and recursive.

Recursive (example):

```
def fib(n):
  if n < 0:
    raise Exception("Invalid Fib Input")
  elif n == 0:
    return 0
  elif n == 1:
    return 1

  return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
```

Iterative (example):

```
def fib(n):
  x = 0
  y = 1
  z = 1
  
  for i in range(0, n):
    x = y;
    y = z;
    z = x + y;
  
  return x;
```

Both implementations of the Fibonacci series will work. Now, we can run the following code to print every other Fibonacci number.

```
for i in range(1, 100, 2):
  print(fib(i))
```

And we are now done. Feel free to ask if you need more clarification. If you want to know how to implement a more efficient solution, look into dynamic programming and storing intermediate values.